# Parsing nested elements with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

example taken from : https://www.quebec.ca/en/health/health-issues/a-z/2019-coronavirus/situation-coronavirus-in-quebec/#c70322

I want to find/select `table` below:

[image]
[image]

This `table` in question is inside

```
<div id="c63027" ...> 
  <a ..>
  <div ...>
    <table ...> <-- this one I want
    ...
```

I'm trying to find/select with the code below but no success:

```
target_div = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id': 'c63027'})

inner_div = target_div.find('div', attrs = {'id': 'csv-display-cas-par-region' })

target_table = inner_div.find('table') <--- returns None
```

Question : How can I find/select the `table` I want?

Comment: Have you printed / saved the html content after loading it in your script? Is the table there? Checking in the browser shows you the html after JavaScript has run - you may need to use something like selenium if it turns out the table isn't there after loading without JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded from external source via Ajax request (so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it). It is in CSV form, so easiest way is to use `pandas` (but you can use `requests`/`csv` modules as well):

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://cdn-contenu.quebec.ca/cdn-contenu/sante/documents/Problemes_de_sante/covid-19/csv/cas-region.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(url, sep=";")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                 Régions sociosanitaires  2021-05-30  2021-05-31 Total des cas confirmés depuis le début de la pandémie
0                 01 - Bas-Saint-Laurent           6           3                                              3 906    
1         02 - Saguenay – Lac-Saint-Jean           7           5                                             10 901    
2                03 - Capitale-Nationale          16           9                                             32 587    
3      04 - Mauricie-et-Centre-du-Québec           3           9                                             15 078    
4                            05 - Estrie          20          28                                             14 731    
5                          06 - Montréal          79          35                                            131 208    
6                         07 - Outaouais          16          18                                             12 219    
7             08 - Abitibi-Témiscamingue           0           1                                              1 114    
8                         09 - Côte-Nord           0           0                                                571    
9                    10 - Nord-du-Québec           0           0                                                109    
10  11 - Gaspésie – Îles-de-la-Madeleine           3           2                                              2 019    
11             12 - Chaudière-Appalaches          31          28                                             18 926    
12                            13 - Laval          17          11                                             31 228    
13                       14 - Lanaudière           9          14                                             23 790    
14                      15 - Laurentides          13          11                                             20 762    
15                       16 - Montérégie          56          34                                             50 783    
16                          17 - Nunavik           0           0                                                 47    
17    18 - Terres-Cries-de-la-Baie-James           0           0                                                119    
18                           Hors Québec           0           0                                                426    
19                   Région à déterminer           0           0                                                  3    
20                                 Total         276         208                                            370 527
```

Comment: I need to use `beautifulsoup` for this purpose and use pandas for later parsing

Comment: @yuntres With `beautifulsoup` you don't get this data - the data is loaded from external source, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't "see it"